# Install software on wine as a normal user (not as administrator)

Tags: ubuntu, wine, tidal

I am trying to install the tidal windows application in Ubuntu 18.04 (its actually xubuntu). However, when i run `wine TIDALSetup.exe` to install it, it says that the Installation has failed and says that I should re run the installer as a normal user and not "as Administrator". Obviously the installer thinks that I am using windows are have chosen to run it as an administrator. So how can I install the program not as an admin?

Thank you.

Comment: Let me know if anything happens here, please.

Answer (score 0):

This [silent installation guide](https://silentinstallhq.com/tidal-silent-install-how-to-guide/) does say Tidal should be installed as administrator (elevated):

> 3. Open an **Elevated Command Prompt**
> 4. Enter the following command: `TIDALSetup.exe -s`

---

But if Tidal still complains, you can manually de-elevate wine like so:

```
wine runas /trustlevel:0x20000 TIDALSetup.exe
```

Comment: The runas executable no longer exists. However, I found an alternate solution.

Comment: What was your alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out wine-staging now runs programs as non-Administrator by default, then bumps them up to Administrator as needed. I encountered the described problem when using Bottles, which does not use wine-staging by default.